# How can I increment the value of a variable within dictionary comprehension

Tags: python, dictionary-comprehension

```
start = 0
limit = 100
count = 10
total_count = 1000
pages = {}
for i in range(1, count+1):
    pages[i] = start
    start += limit
print pages
{1: 0, 2: 100, 3: 200, 4: 300, 5: 400, 6: 500, 7: 600, 8: 700, 9: 800, 10: 900}
```

How can I achieve the same result using dictionary comprehension? I can't seem to be able to increment the value of variable 'start' after each iteration with dict comprehension.

Is it possible to achieve the same result comprehension?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use mathematics:

```
pages = {(i+1): 100 * i for i in range(count)}
```

Since `start` starts at zero and keeps adding `100`, we can use multiplication to find where it should be at each point.  If `start` and `limit` aren't always going to be what they are here, you can still do this:

```
pages = {(i+1): start + (limit * i) for i in range(count)}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
start = 0
limit = 100
count = 10
pages2 = {(i + 1): start + i * limit for i in range(count)}
print pages2
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this question when I was looking for a solution to increment a variable which I want to be a part of each key in the dictionary. 
The solutions here didn't assist in my case so I used Python's enumerate() method for that. Here's what my solution would look like for the question posted here:

```
    start = 0
    limit = 100
    count = 10
    pages2 = {(j + 1): start + i * limit for i, j in enumerate(range(count))}
    print(pages2)
```